# Display double quotes in html input values from database

Tags: php, html, sql-server, input

This is my php code. For an example:

```
<?php
while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $ItmName = $row['ItemName'];
        }
?>
```

This is my html:

```
<input type="text" id="ItmName" name="ItmName" value="<?php echo $ItmName; ?>" />
```

If the data is as such `3" FILE` which have `double quotes`, in the textbox field it will only be displayed as:

`3`

which it supposed to be

`3" FILE`

but IF the data is `3' FILE` which is a single quote, it will be displayed as `3' FILE`. So there's no problem. So my question is, how to display the data with the `double quotes` in a HTML `input's value`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Always *always* **always** escape output that you don't *trust*.

Use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/htmlspecialchars) (or [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities)) to escape strings so they are safe to use in HTML.

Comment: if i use single quotes on the html values, is it okay? like `value='$ItmName'`

Comment: No. It will break again if `$itmName` happens to contain a `'`.

Comment: U're right. Forgot bout that. Thanks! It works. I mean i never know there's a `htmlspecialchars` on php :')

Comment: You need to know about that function. It's your best bet at preventing XSS attacks.

Comment: Really? Wow i don't know a lot. Still a beginner. But thank you! :)